# Counterexample for $\prod_{i<\nu} \kappa_i=(\sup_{i<\nu}\kappa_i)^{\nu}$ when $\kappa_i$ is not an increasing $\nu$-sequence of cardinals

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

It is known that $\displaystyle \prod_{i<\nu} \kappa_i=\left(\sup_{i<\nu} \kappa_i \right)^{\nu}$ if $\nu$ is an infinite cardinal and $\langle \kappa_i | i < \nu \rangle$ is an increasing $\nu$-sequence of infinite cardinals.
I'm stuck at finding a counterexample if the increasing monotony hypothesis doesn't hold.
I tried writing $\nu=\nu \times \nu$ or using $cof(\nu)$ in some ways, but the most that I have achieved is that I should obtain $\displaystyle \prod_{i<\nu} \kappa_i<\left(\sup_{i<\nu} \kappa_i \right)^{\nu}$ cause the inequality with $\le$ is always true.

Comment: You want to study this paper: *[On a conjecture of Tarski on products of cardinals](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1991-112-04/S0002-9939-1991-1070525-1/home.html)* by Jech and Shelah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $\lambda$ to be some cardinal such that:

1. $\lambda>(\sup\kappa_i)^\nu$,
2. $\operatorname{cf}(\lambda)\leq\nu$.

Now define $\lambda_0=\lambda$ and $\lambda_{1+\alpha}=\kappa_\alpha$ for all $\alpha<\nu$. Then we have $$\prod_{i<\nu}\lambda_i = \lambda\times\prod_{i<\nu}\kappa_i=\lambda\times(\sup\kappa_i)^\nu=\lambda<\lambda^{\operatorname{cf}(\lambda)}\leq\lambda^\nu=(\sup\lambda_i)^\nu.$$

Comment: How do I know that such a $\lambda$ exists?

Comment: Because $((\sup\kappa_i)^\nu)^{+\omega}$ exists?

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Asaf,(+1) That $\lambda_{1+\alpha}$ is a neat trick to avoid messy definitions! I will remember that. :)

Comment: @Shervin: Yes, it was born through salt and smoke and massive pain in keeping up with similar indexation problems. :-P